# Carbon Error in Internet Explorer 11 / Microsoft Edge

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, internet-explorer, php-carbon

I've recently discovered that my website produces error in Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge. Works well on all other browsers.

Error occures, when im using Carbon to create a date in Laravel.

Code:

```
$date = new Carbon(request('date'));
```

request('date') is like "YYYY-mm-dd", and its working perfectly in other browsers.

Error I get on this line is:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (‎2018-‎06-‎13) at position 0 (�): Unexpected character

I've tried a lot of other methods, to create the Carbon instance, all working fine in other borsers, but not in these.

Any idea, what could couse the problem?

EDIT: 
The data sent by the javascript is a string in this case "2018-06-13". I've tried to explode the string, and reconnect again, and convert some other ways. 
It says string(10) "2018-06-13" in most of the browsers, 
and string(19) "‎2018-‎06-‎13" in internet explorer, which is really wierd.

EDIT2:
Script for creating the days for the calendar (Vue2.js):

```
weeks: function () {
            var dayCount = this.calendar.days(this.displayedYear, this.displayedMonth),
                dayIndex = this.calendar.day(this.displayedYear, this.displayedMonth, 0).getDay(),
                weekCount = Math.ceil((dayCount + dayIndex) / 7);

            var weeks = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < weekCount; i++) {
                var week = [];

                for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    var date = new Date(
                        this.displayedYear,
                        this.displayedMonth - 1,
                        i * 7 + j - dayIndex + 1
                    );

                    week.push(
                        date.getMonth() === this.displayedMonth - 1
                            ? date : null
                    );
                }

                weeks[i] = week;
            }

            return weeks;
```

Blade for displaying:

```
<tr v-for="week in weeks()">
                <td
                        v-for="day in week"
                        @click="setSelectionPivot(day)"
                        :class="classes(day)">
                    <span>
                        @{{ (day == null) ? '' : day.getDate() }}
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Function part to process:

```
this.selection = day;
```

Then I pass this with ajax to the code the error occures. Ask if anything else is needed. 
The thing I don't understand is how it works perfectly in any other browser?

Comment: If you state that the request is "like" something, can you share real data from successful and failing attempts?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the way the browser sends the data to the server and not Carbon. Could you show us the form or javascript that generates this request?

Comment: I think the problem is not related to PHP but to the way the data is sent to the server. it seems that you have an invisible character before your date string and that leads to an error. you have to show the code you use to send the data

Comment: you have to show the code used to send the data

Comment: Code is quite complex, and spread in 4 files. Which part you exactly need? The part where the Date is created?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to check which browser client is using if it is Internet Explorer 11/Microsoft Edge then parse date like this:

```
$req->time->toDateTime()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s A')    //I assume you already get time value from view
```

To check which browser client is using follow this link:[PHP function to get browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Before the Carbon instance I just do this:

```
$date = preg_replace('/[^0-9, -]/', '', request('date'));
$date = new Carbon($date);
```

And it removed the 9 random character. Still dont know why it happened, in IE and Edge.